# Qt + VS2010 compiler: How to create a simple project that would use compiled for VC staticaly linked boost?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt, boost

How to create a simple project that would use compiled for VC staticaly linked boost (that is somewhhere like C:/boost)? How shall my project file look like?

I tried to add to .pro

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/BOOST/include/boost-1_49
DEPENDPATH += C:/BOOST/lib
 LIBS += -LC:/BOOST/lib -llibboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49 -llibboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49
```

but I get:

```
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll):-1: ERROR: LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib(error_code.obj)

msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll):-1: ERROR: LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib(error_code.obj)

msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll):-1: ERROR: LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_49.lib(error_code.obj)

:-1: WARNING: LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

debug\loader.exe:-1: ERROR: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

when I try to compile something like:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::filesystem::path p;
}
```

So I wonder how shall I change my .proo file to link correctly to static boost compiled for VC using Qt Creator that is using VS compiler?

Comment: For boost there are special directives in the headers which make the linker automatically link against needed libraries (for Visual Studio only). I have nothing to do to statically link against boost on my machine, just including the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you built boost with the `--runtime-link=static` flag then they were compiled against the static CRT libraries, i.e. using the `/MT` (and `/MTd` for debug) compiler flags.

Your errors suggest your project is trying to link with the dynamic CRT lib, i.e. using `/MD` and `/MDd`.  If these are set in your .pro file, they will be a part of the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG` variables.  They might however not be listed at all - I think the default is to use the dynamic CRT lib.

All the libraries in your project need to link against the same CRT.

You either need to use `--runtime-link=shared` when building boost (you can still use `--link=static` to create static boost libs with this option though), or add/change the `/MD` and `/MDd` to `/MT` and `/MTd` in your .pro file.